Questions in small proof regarding cross product of shape operator
So I came across this small, for a lemma in the shape operator chapter. I get the gist of it and I'm sure it's quite elementary but two questions did arise.This is a screenshot of the complete proof. It is from a free sample chapter of the textbook and can be found here on page 219.
So, on to my questions:
1) I understand that even though we are talking about objects embedded in $R^3$ (surfaces) the tangent space to a point of the surface is a two-dimensional vector space and so we can define the matrix representation of the shape operator w.r.t. any basis to be $2x2$.
Indeed this is exactly what the author does in the proof. But, since the vectors are two-dimensional and contained withing a plane, how can we even define a cross product between them?
2) How are the coefficients pulled out of the cross product in the form of the determinant in the transition between the second to last and last lines? It may be some application of the BAC-CAB rule that I'm too rusty in multivariable calculus to catch? I've went over wikipedia overviews of cross product properties but I seem to be missing something crucial
Thank you all so much in advance! I've tried to format my question properly but do let me know if I did something wrong, still fairly new here.

Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using MathJax) instead of posting links to pictures.

This is about surfaces in $\Bbb R^3$, and the cross product is of vectors in $\Bbb R^3$. For your second question, just expand by the distributive law, and remember that $\mathbf v\times\mathbf v = \mathbf 0$.
